# Mapbox-iOS-SDK 6.3.0 pod install error 403 Forbidden

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mapbox-ios

download Mapbox example, run pod install, error: 403 Forbidden, why? please help, thank you!

pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 6.3.0'

> ➜  ios-sdk-examples-298e050be7352eb28cee6f03e02945593140c1f3 pod
> install Analyzing dependencies Downloading dependencies Installing
> Mapbox-iOS-SDK 6.3.0
>
> [!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o
> /var/folders/84/rnxy4n6d32g03yxywry6hlnx0l2qqr/T/d20210316-90167-1gkenam/file.zip
> https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.3.0/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip
> --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.10.0 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--     0 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

```
machine api.mapbox.com
  login xxx
  password xxx <sk.eyJ1IjoiY2hpYnVkb25nIiwiYSI6ImNrbWJlN2RhNzIwcTEyb210ZTRtbXM2MDAifQ.DkqGccMXylJmAG9G6OSfYg>
```

Comment: You can remove the secret token, it could be misused.

Comment: What worked for me was to create another token and use that one.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure that you have `DOWNLOADS:READ` permission when creating the secret token.

[image]

Comment: This was made my day

Answer (score 3):

you should edit your .netrc file to:


machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password sk.eyJ1IjoiY2hpYnVkb25nIiwiYSI6ImNrbWJlN2RhNzIwcTEyb210ZTRtbXM2MDAifQ.DkqGccMXylJmAG9G6OSfYg


and you should take your SECRET TOKEN instead of default PUBLIC TOKEN

Comment: You can remove the secret token, it could be misused.

Comment: that is not important

Answer (score 0):

You must have a SECRET token from MapBox (not public).

> Note: a SECRET token is created when you grant any "Secret Scopes" when creating the token in the Mapbox dashboard.

Then create this file and add your SECRET token:

```
touch ~/.netrc
echo "machine api.mapbox.com" > ~/.netrc
echo "login mapbox" >> ~/.netrc
echo "password <INSERT SECRET TOKEN>" >> ~/.netrc
```

Now `pod install` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with netrbut I have another problem when I use code push it’s success but doesn’t update reflect in real device so I go to app center and build with GitHub source code I got mapbox authorization error what should I do ? Btw sry for my English