# Cocoapods Error - Trouble in installing MapboxNavigation podfile -Mapboxnavigation sdk

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mapbox, mapbox-navigation

In order to implement **MapbocNavigation** podfile according to *mapboxnavigationsdk* official documentation.adding Mapbox-iOS-SDK and MapboxNavigation through Cocoapods, always get error, shown bellow.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30y89.png)

Also tried: Generate access token and use secret key from Mapbox account and also configure .nertc file with secret key, follow all the steps of .nertc file configuration and research more about this error and implement all the possible ways but yet I am facing this error...

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648473/mapbox-ios-sdk-6-3-0-pod-install-error-403-forbidden

Comment: I have tried this one also but, yet facing same error. Do you have any other solution @teja_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please remove already created .netrc files with this command.

```
sed -i '' '/^machine api.mydomain.com$/{N;N;d;}' ~/.netrc
```

Then Try To create new .netrc file with this steps:

To create .netrc file do next

```
Fire up Terminal
cd ~ (go to the home directory)
touch .netrc (create file)
open .netrc (open .netrc)
Set required data.
Save
```

.netrc file should be like this

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password <secret_key_created_from_your_mapbox_account>
```

May be it will help to you. If Its Help then please upvote to my answer.